# Finding out which DOM element is rendered first

Tags: angularjs

I have a tabs based navigation system, and some of the tabs are hidden by an `ng-if` by a security infrastrucutre.
I need to find which tab is rendered first.
The solution we found so far is adding the function which is called by `ng-click`, to `ng-init`:

```
ng-click="vm.getAttributeTab()"
ng-init="vm.getAttributeTab(1)"
```

and then at each controller raising a flag to indicate which tab was rendered first:

```
function getAttributeTab(init) {
            if (init && vm.firstTabLoaded)
                return;
            if (init)
                vm.firstTabLoaded = true;
```

Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Just an opinion, but i think using a different function with a proper name would be more "elegant", actually easier to read and maintain for future coders.

Comment: @Kaddath Thanks for the comment. I'm actually looking for a better approach rather than just a rename.

Comment: that's why i started by "opinion" and didn't make an answer. By the way, usually, when people ask for a more elegant solution, it's that the way they use bothers them. What bothers you with using `init`? Most solutions i would think would be much more hackish..

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Using ng-init is generally bad idea, as well as your logic should never depend on 'which element is rendered first'.

Comment: @Kaddath the fact I call ng-click and then ng-init, both for the same function. It's code smell

Comment: @PetrAveryanov the problem is that the model for each directive is retrieved on click (when user clicks the tab header), but the first tab loads automatically, without the user clicking it (the user actually clicks another menu's item, but I don't want to catch that, it would mess my code up..). I'm trying to retrieve the model without clicking.